# Image is displayed at design but not at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a solution with a portable class library called Domain. Domain contains a folder called Images. There are png images inside of it.

Blank-Solution:

- Domain (Portable Library)

  - Images

    - Avatar.png
- WPF-Project

I have a WPF-project inside my solution, too. If I reference the Domain.dll in my WPF-project and write:

```
 <Image Source="/Domain;component/Images/Avatar.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

The image is displayed in my designer. But there is no images if I run my WPF-app.

I have tried

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Domain;component/Images/Avatar.png"

Build Action to embedded Resource or content
```

without any success...

Is there a way to get this work? I know that I could add the images direct in the WPF-project and Build Action to Resource, but I want the described approach...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you added the image directly into the folder or through visual studio ?

Comment: Build Action must be `Resource`, not `Embedded Resource`.

Comment: Right-click the image in your solution and select "Properties". What is the `Copy to Output Directory` set as?

Comment: @GeoffJames A resource file isn't copied to the output directory. It is contained in the assembly.

Comment: Ah, good point @Clemens - my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Clemens There is no Resource as Build Action if the Image is located in a portable class library

Comment: Ok, then a WPF Resource File Pack URI won't work with an image in a PCL.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

**siteoforigin** is the key

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/Avatar.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

I can't see the image at design time - however it works at runtime